# Flutter | Retrieve ffprobe data

Tags: flutter, dart, ffmpeg, ffprobe

I'm using `flutter_ffmpeg` package, specifically I'm trying to retrieve information regarding the chapter marks from a `.m4b` file which is an audiobook. By using this method:

```
_flutterFFmpeg.executeWithArguments(['-i', widget.book.path, '-print_format', 'json', '-show_chapters', '-loglevel', 'error']);
```

I was able to output this data as a JSON map in the console. The thing is, I need to use this data inside my application, is there a way to get access to those chapters as a variable using another approach, or maybe to access this data directly from the console log printed by the method shown earlier.